# Magento 2 how to check serialized conditions against product in frontend?

Tags: frontend, magento2.3, catalog-rules, product-listing, product-view-page

I have created an admin form which contains name and catalog price rule conditions. I have saved these values in a custom table. The conditions are saved as serialized. Now I want to check these conditions against each product in catalog product list page, product page, widgets etc. If the condition satisfied then need to display the name in each product.

How can I do this. Please help me.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this

Comment: Did you get any solution for this, please share

Answer (score 0):

You can use as example the standard Magento class `Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel` or just extend it in your custom class. The algorithm is pretty simple:

1) Load conditions data (`$conditionsSerialized = $this->getConditionsSerialized())`) and unserialize it (`$conditions = $this->serializer->unserialize($conditionsSerialized);`)

2) Get the conditions object (instance of `\Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Combine` or what ever you use) and load it using recently loaded data as array (`$this->_conditions->loadArray($conditions);`)

3) Validate your object using this condition (`$this->_conditions->validate($object);`)

Comment: This validate only the customer group, dates and website Ids. I want to validate against the product too. ie, in product view I want to check the rule is applicable for this product or not

Comment: @JancyAbraham The conditions class is responsible for the product validation, so you should update it if you wish to add custom validation.

Comment: Can you please explain it briefly.

Comment: @JancyAbraham I'll try to create a simple example for you with all classes

Comment: Can I get the example please.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

Native PHP method:

```php
    /**
     * Check if value is serialised
     *
     * @param string $data
     * @param bool $strict
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isSerialised(string $data, bool $strict = true): bool
    {
        try {
            // If it isn't a string, it isn't serialized.
            if (!is_string($data)) {
                return false;
            }
            $data = trim($data);
            if ('N;' === $data) {
                return true;
            }
            if (strlen($data) < 4) {
                return false;
            }
            if (':' !== $data[1]) {
                return false;
            }
            if ($strict) {
                $lastc = substr($data, -1);
                if (';' !== $lastc && '}' !== $lastc) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                $semicolon = strpos($data, ';');
                $brace     = strpos($data, '}');
                // Either ; or } must exist.
                if (false === $semicolon && false === $brace) {
                    return false;
                }
                // But neither must be in the first X characters.
                if (false !== $semicolon && $semicolon < 3) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (false !== $brace && $brace < 4) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            $token = $data[0];
            switch ($token) {
                case 's':
                    if ($strict) {
                        if ('"' !== substr($data, -2, 1)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    } elseif (false === strpos($data, '"')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    // Or else fall through.
                case 'a':
                case 'O':
                    return (bool) preg_match("/^{$token}:[0-9]+:/s", $data);
                case 'b':
                case 'i':
                case 'd':
                    $end = $strict ? '$' : '';
                    return (bool) preg_match("/^{$token}:[0-9.E+-]+;$end/", $data);
            }
            return false;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks to [Wordpress core code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_serialized/)

## Option 2

Use `Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface`

```php
    /**
     * Check if value is serialised
     *
     * @param string $string
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isSerialised(string $string): bool
    {
        try {
            $unserialised = $this->serialize->unserialize($string);
            return (is_array($unserialised))
                ? true
                : false;

        } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

## Option 3

Steal code from `Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface` (in case you don't have access to it for whatever reason).

```php
    /**
     * JSON Encode Serialisation (stolen from Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface) but I didn't want to use constructors here ;)
     *
     * @see Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface
     * @param string $string
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function unserialise(string $string)
    {
        $result = json_decode($string, true);
        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unable to unserialize value. Error: " . json_last_error_msg());
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Check if value is serialised
     *
     * @param string $string
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isSerialised(string $string): bool
    {
        try {
            $unserialised = $this->unserialise($string);
            return (is_array($unserialised))
                ? true
                : false;

        } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```